# get Undefined variable: plugin_dir error while I have defined the variable before

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

wordpress plugin has only one php file.

I just tried to set **icon** variable to the file path on server:

```
public function __construct() {

            $this->id                 = 'offline_gateway';
            $this->icon               = apply_filters('woocommerce_offline_icon', $plugin_dir.'\assets\custompay.png' );
            $this->has_fields         = false;
            $this->method_title       = __( 'Offline', 'wc-gateway-offline' );
            $this->method_description = __( 'Allows offline payments. Very handy if you use your cheque gateway for another payment method, and can help with testing. Orders are marked as "on-hold" when received.', 'wc-gateway-offline' );   
.
.
.
   }
```

and added this line to define **$plugin_dir** variable exactly after `defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or exit;` in the beginning of the code:

```
$plugin_dir = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-offline/';
```

But I received this php error :

> Notice: Undefined variable: plugin_dir in
>   /home/username/public_html/sitename/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-offline/woocommerce-gateway-offline.php
>
> ### > on line 95

Based on @the-alpha hints, I used `define('WGO_PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));` but the output URL is like follow link which is wrong:

> https://sitename.com/home/user/public_html/site-folder/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-offline/assets/custompay.png

How can I get the correct URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a global variable inside any method or  function without using `global variablename`, so you can use something like this in your constructor:

```
public function __construct() {
    global $plugin_dir; // <---

    $this->id                 = 'offline_gateway';
    $this->icon               = apply_filters('woocommerce_offline_icon', $plugin_dir.'\assets\custompay.png' );
    $this->has_fields         = false;
    $this->method_title       = __( 'Offline', 'wc-gateway-offline' );
    $this->method_description = __( 'Allows offline payments. Very handy if you use your cheque gateway for another payment method, and can help with testing. Orders are marked as "on-hold" when received.', 'wc-gateway-offline' );

}
```

Alternatively, you can define a constant like:

```
define('PLUGIN_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-offline/');
```

Then you can directly use it anywhere, like:

```
apply_filters('woocommerce_offline_icon', PLUGIN_DIR.'\assets\custompay.png');
```

Btw, you shouldn't use hard-coded `path`, instead you may use [plugin_dir_path](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/) (inside your main plugin file), for example:

```
// Note: Use a prefix, i.e: WGO_PLUGIN_DIR (woocommerce-gateway-offline)
define('PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
```

*Note: Always use a unique prefix to any global variable/constant in WordPress.*

Comment: Thank you so much @the-alpha; That error is removed but the icon route is not correct! I see this url for rendered image: https://sitename.com/home/user/public_html/site-folder/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-offline/assets/custompay.png - Should I change something else in file?

Comment: I used this code instead and it is working fine: `WP_PLUGIN_URL . "/" . plugin_basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/assets/custompay.png'` . Of course I have not defined WP_PLUGIN_URL constant in beginning of file but it is working.